# Python pyghmi (IPMI) unable to connect to server

Tags: python, salt-stack, ipmi

I've been trying to get SaltStack to work with IPMI, looking at the source code I see the ipmi module uses pythons [pyghmi](https://github.com/openstack/pyghmi), no matter what I try I always get the following error:

`Insufficient resources to create new session (wait for existing sessions to timeout)`

However, using ipmitool from command line (with the same username and password) works fine, I'm able to connect and execute commands.

Also I've tried with a simple python script:

```
from pyghmi.ipmi.private import session


def _onlogon(response):
    if 'error' in response:
        raise Exception(response['error'])

s = session.Session(bmc='10.0.0.100',
                    userid='USER',
                    password='PASS',
                    onlogon=_onlogon)
```

But that fails with the same error (tried with python 2.7 and 3.5):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/pycharm_project_858/main.py", line 15, in <module>
    s.wait_for_rsp(timeout=1)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyghmi/ipmi/private/session.py", line 1103, in wait_for_rsp
    relsession.process_pktqueue()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyghmi/ipmi/private/session.py", line 1194, in process_pktqueue
    self._handle_ipmi_packet(pkt[0], sockaddr=pkt[1], qent=pkt)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyghmi/ipmi/private/session.py", line 1261, in _handle_ipmi_packet
    self._handle_ipmi2_packet(data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyghmi/ipmi/private/session.py", line 1283, in _handle_ipmi2_packet
    return self._got_rmcp_response(data[16:])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyghmi/ipmi/private/session.py", line 1363, in _got_rmcp_response
    self.onlogon({'error': errstr})
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyghmi/ipmi/private/session.py", line 537, in onlogon
    waiter(parameter)
  File "/tmp/pycharm_project_858/main.py", line 6, in _onlogon
    raise Exception(response['error'])
Exception: Insufficient resources to create new session (wait for existing sessions to timeout)
```

Any insight would be welcome, I couldn't find any documentation about pyghmi unfortunately.

Comment: Do you have the config setup for ipmi or are you passing through the settings to the module?  https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/modules/all/salt.modules.ipmi.html

Comment: I'm passing the settings to the module `salt-call ipmi.fast_connect_test api_host="10.0.0.100" api_user="USER" api_password="PASS"`

Answer (score 0):

From the docs it looks like you should be using

https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/modules/all/salt.modules.ipmi.html#salt.modules.ipmi.fast_connect_test

```
api_host=127.0.0.1
api_user=admin
api_pass=example
api_port=623
api_kg=None
```

So `api_pass` instead of `api_password`.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't help, I should have mentioned I try connecting with a simple python script also, I've updated my question.

Comment: Unfortunate, I would ask https://ask.openstack.org/en/questions/ since this is their project. https://github.com/openstack/pyghmi